# Specify type when adding data to Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add data to Firestore but I need to save it as a number. The problem is, Firestore automatically stores everything as a string by default. How do you change this?

```
  //Add to Firestore
  this.afs.collection(placeToSearchSubmit).add({
    title: thingName,
    type: thingType,
    value: thingValue    <-- I need this to be a number
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Adding `+` at the front of a variable automatically casts it to an integer, but it's not the only way.

**Example**

```
let thing2 = +thing.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't store everything as a string untill you give it as a string  type. For info please check these two link:-
[DATA TYPE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)

[Add Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)